# Distinct Comma separated values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string as '1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7' stored in a column.
I need distinct comma separated value as output using sql query.

e.g. For given string output should be '1,2,3,4,5,6,7'. No duplicacy persists in output.

Comment: Hi, not sure that doing it with oracle is the good way to go. Couldn't you enforce unicity at insertion or parse your string client-side ?

Comment: Create a function which takes this column value as parameter and returns a string with duplicates removed.

Answer (score 3):

without regexp:

```
WITH t AS
( SELECT '1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7' AS num FROM dual
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       SUBSTR (
         num
       , instr(num, ',', 1, level) + 1
       , instr(num, ',', 1, level + 1) - instr(num, ',', 1, level) - 1)
        AS numbers
FROM (select ','||num||',' num from t)
CONNECT BY level <= length(num) - length(replace(num,',')) -1
```

with regexp:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR( '1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7' , '[^,]+', 1, lvl)
FROM DUAL, 
(SELECT LEVEL lvl
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH( '1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7' ) - LENGTH(REPLACE( '1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7' , ','))+1)
WHERE lvl <= LENGTH( '1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7' ) - LENGTH(REPLACE( '1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7' , ',')) + 1
```

Comment: `ORA-00904: "REGEXP_SUBSTR": invalid identifier` occurs in Oracle 9i

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using regex_substr and connect by. Please try this.

```
 select distinct num from
(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7','[^,]+',1,level) as num
FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY LEVEL<= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE('1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7','[^,]','')));
```

Without regex:
After some clarification in the question

```
 with t as (SELECT distinct substr(replace('1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7',','),level,1)||',' as num
 FROM DUAL
 CONNECT BY LEVEL<=  LENGTH( '1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7' ) - LENGTH(REPLACE( '1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7' , ','))+1)
 select listagg(num) within group (order by num) from t;
```

Comment: `ORA-00904: "REGEXP_REPLACE": invalid identifier` occurs in Oracle

Comment: which oracle version you are using?? I think regexp is for 10g

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select
  regexp_replace('1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7', '([^,]+),\1', '\1')
from 
   dual;
```

However, this wont work if your input string contains a figure more than twice. If this bothers you, you might want to try

```
select
  regexp_replace('1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,7', '([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1')
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

According my point of view:

```
select wm_concat(distinct substr(replace('1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7',',',''),level,1)) as out     
from dual connect by level <= length('1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  listagg(ra,',')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ra)
FROM
(
  SELECT
  DISTINCT (REGEXP_SUBSTR('02,02,02,02,02,03,04,03', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) )ra
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('02,02,02,02,02,03,04,03', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS 
  NOT NULL
);
```